# Run a screen scrape Python script on IIS - Not working

Tags: python, iis, selenium-chromedriver, scrape, webapi

**Project Scope**
Run Python .py screen scrape script on IIS server that opens a Google Chrome window (using chromedriver.exe). The .py script opens Chrome to a particular website, enters the arguments and captures the final result.  Result is then displaying using a Print command.
I am able to run the following code on a WebAPI call and test it a web app.  Web App calls the web api function, which in turns executes the .py script.  Everything works fine on my local computer.

**On The Server**
I am able to manually execute .py script on the server using command prompt.  It works as designed and gives me the results on the command prompt.

**Issue**
When I publish this Web API on server (IIS) and try the test Web App, it does not work.  The code goes all the way to "End of Function" call at the bottom without any errors thrown.

I tried setting the AppPool to LocalSystem, Network Service, a custom user (with execute permission on all folders), but nothing starts the process.

```
try
            {
                var script = @"C:\Installs\ProdCode\ScreenScraping\trancounttest.py";
                var process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = @"C:\Installs\Python377\python.exe",
                        Arguments = $"\"{script}\"",
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    }
                };

                process.Start();
                var line = "";

                while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    return line;
                }


                process.WaitForExit();
                return "End of Function";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: dose your script required any user interaction?

Comment: I tried a script with no parameters and a script with parameters, both do not work on IIS.  Both work OK on my laptop when I run in debug mode.  There is no manual user interaction required for the script

Comment: as i said what you are trying to achieve is not support by iis. you could try to use Headless browser/Selenium